# Issue deploying AWS Lambda Function from Eclipse with Resource folder

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I'm having trouble with the way the AWS deploys AWS Java Lambda functions. I have an Eclipse Maven Project that I deploy to AWS as a Lambda Function.

Here is what my structure looks like:

[image]

Within `resources`, there is a forms folder that contains PDF files I need to load. I can do that locally just fine with the following:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url =  classLoader.getResource( "forms/myform.pdf" );
```

However, this only works locally and does not work when it is deployed to AWS. Here is what the folder structure looks like when it gets deployed to AWS.

[image]

Therefore, I have to change my code to the following to get it to work.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url =  classLoader.getResource( "./resources/forms/myform.pdf" );
```

How can I get this to work locally and in AWS? I could have a properties file for the location when running on AWS vs local, but I was trying to avoid having to have something like that.

For deploying to AWS, I'm just following their [documentation on deploying lambda functions with the Eclipse toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html). I also asked a [similar questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252738/unable-to-load-file-from-resources-folder-when-running-app-locally)n about this, thinking that it was an issue with how I was running it locally. But now I see that it has to do with how it is being deployed.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work locally or on AWS? Is there a way to change the AWS toolkit to deploy the resources differently?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can just change the resources for the Maven project:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then I can reference the path the same locally and in AWS:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url =  classLoader.getResource( "./resources/forms/myform.pdf" );
```